# How to rename an already loaded file using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rename, carrierwave

I want to rename the already downloaded files carrierwave. In the uploader, I added the following code to the new files loaded with the desired name me.

was:

```
def filename
  "photo.jpg" if original_filename
end
```

became:

```
def filename
  "#{secure_token}.jpg" if original_filename
end

protected
def secure_token
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end
```

Already downloaded files I tried to re-create using rake task:

```
RoutePointPhoto.all.each { |i| i.photo.recreate_versions! }
```

This creates a copy of the file with the correct name. But in the database, the file name remains the same "photo.jpg" 
Prompt what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

what I did was I created a documents controller where I manager the files. on the show action is where the renaming is happening

```
#documents_controller.rb
  def show
    data = open(document.file_url.to_s)
    #change #{'photo'} to what every you want to call the file 
    send_data data.read, filename: "#{'photo'}.#{document.file_identifier.split('.').last}", disposition: 'inline'
  end
```

I hope that this works for what you are looking